# Enabling Seo Url in opencart - Checkout and Cart page not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart

I am enabling seo in opencart. After enabling the same in it, checkout, cart and login page stopped working. I have enabled SSL also in it. I am using AWS as the hosting server.

I have also renamed `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess` file.

Please if any one can tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: share your htaccess file

Comment: clear cache and try

Answer (score 0):

When you stay stopped working, are you saying that they stopped working, or they are not SEO friendly (the SEO rewrite is not working for them)?

Please provide your htaccess and the error you're getting when you pull up the page